# How to set up NetBean's debugger

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, ubuntu-12.04

I want to start using debugger in NetBeans but when I hit debug Main Project I am keep getting:

```
    Have no file for /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/modules/jdk.boot.jar
```

Window perspective doesn't change. I am almost certain that I have not change any settings since installation.

Ubuntu 12.04
NetBeand 6.9.1

Comment: Any specific reason you are using such an outdated version?

Comment: Outdated version of what? Java? Needed this version of java while working with servlets.

Comment: Works well under newest version. Thanks!